# Camera not stretching to width of android device

Tags: java, eclipse, android-layout, android-camera, surfaceview

In my android camera app, Im trying to make it so that the camera layout view fills the width of the screen and then is proportional (to a square) for the height of the layout. But its cropping it too small for some reason:

[example of what is happening..](http://oi57.tinypic.com/ua8gy.jpg)

The green arrow represents where it should go to.

Ive tried fill_parent, etc. So, how can I make it go to the end of the screen?

I believe this is the problem. I know I did this because I was not sure how to make it automatically stretch to the right proportion.

```
    int width = 352;
    int height = 288;

    camPreview = new CameraSurfaceView(width, height);

    myCamHolder.addCallback(camPreview);
```

Comment: still have not solved this issue. I looked at similar threads but none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = width*288/352;
```

Maybe you don't need `288/352`, but rather `preview size.height/preview size.width`

Comment: thank you. this actually helped me. Except when I rotate the device to landscape the app crashes. not sure if its because of this.

Comment: Does your activity handle _configuration change_, or you let the system reload layout on screen rotation?